# regex to extract address , phone and fax

Tags: python, regex

I have a python string which I retrieved from parsing a webpage.

```
    str1='Suite 100, 2010 Eglinton Avenue West, Toronto ON  M6E 2K3, 
      Phone: (416) 781-2050, Fax: (416) 781-1910'
```

Clearly this str1 has all the data. This string sometimes do not have phone and fax.Like

```
    str1="""Suite 100, 2010 Eglinton Avenue West, Toronto ON  M6E 2K3,"""
```

could somebody please tell me what is the best regex to get the info in both cases in three seperata variables address,phone and fax.

Thanks for the help

Comment: At least include any attempt to start with

Comment: And can you include the URL in case there is a better way?

Comment: These types of questions are not what Stack Overflow is about. It should not be specific usecases, but questions about the more general idea behind using regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex, which captures data in three groups, Address, Phone and Fax and makes Phone and Fax groups as optional,

```
(?<Address>.+)\s*(?:Phone:\s*(?<Phone>[^a-zA-Z]*))?\s*(?:Fax:\s*(?<Fax>.*))?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6LpJMT/1)

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Split by `Phone:` or `Fax:`:

```
import re
str1='Suite 100, 2010 Eglinton Avenue West, Toronto ON  M6E 2K3, Phone: (416) 781-2050, Fax: (416) 781-1910'
re.split("Phone:|Fax:", str1)
```